# Can I include a DLL generated by GCC in a MSVC project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, assembly, gcc, dll

I have a library of code I'm working on upgrading from x86 to x64 for a Windows application.

Part of the code took advantage of MSVC inline assembly blocks.  I'm not looking to go through and interpret the assembly but I am looking to keep functionality from this part of the application.

Can I compile the functions using the inline assembly using GCC to make a DLL and link that to the rest of the library?

EDIT 1:(7/7/21) The flexibility with which compiler the project uses is open and I am currently looking into using Clang for use with MSVC.(also the Intel C++ compiler as another possibility)  As stated in the first sentence it is a Windows application that I want to keep on Windows and the purpose of using another compiler is due to me 1.) not wanting to rewrite the large amount of assembly and 2.) because I know that MSVC does not support x64 inline assembly.  So far clang seems to be working with a couple issues of how it declares comments inside of the assembly block and a few commands.  The function is built around doing mathematical operations on a block of data, in what was supposed to be as fast as possible when it was developed but now that it works as intended I'm not looking to upgrade just maintain functionality.  So, any compiler that will support inline assembly is an option.

EDIT 2:(7/7/21) I forgot to mention in the first edit, I'm not necessarily looking to load the 32-bit DLL into another process because I'm worried about copying data into an out of shared memory.  I've done a similar solution for another project but the data set is around 8 MB and I'm worried that slow copy times for the function would cause the time constraint on the math to cause issues in the runtime of the application.(slow, laggy, and buffering are effects I'm trying to avoid.)  I'm not trying to make it any faster but it definitely can't get any slower.

Comment: What is your target platform?

Comment: The assembly language snippets (for x86-32) are unlikely to work right under x86-64.

Comment: I'm not sure how much flexibility (if any) you have with the compiler you are using, but if you have access to `clang-cl` that would probably be better than `gcc` in terms of MSVC operability -- since that's the `clang` front-end plugged into MSVC's standard library and codegen, which pretty much guarantees compatibility.

Comment: MSVC x64 has no inline assembly blocks.

Comment: The answer is "it depends", please provide a [mre]

Comment: Can you show the snippet? There's a decent chance that such (old?) snippets can be written with intrinsics these days. Otherwise, non-inline assembly (separate files) using the MASM build dependency (already built in in visual studio) seems easier than using GCC or whatever.

Comment: In theory, if you manage to create a plain C interface for that DLL (all exported symbols from DLL are standard C functions)  and don't use memory management functions across "border" (no mixed memory management) then you should be able to **dynamically load that DLL** from another another (MSVC) process and call its functions, at least. Not sure about statically linking against it... probably not, because the compiler and linker must go hand in hand (MSVC compiler+MSVC linker or GCC compiler+GCC linker) . The output of GCC linker is probably not compatible with MSVC

Comment: @Human-Compiler: `clang-cl` is better for *source-level* compatibility with the Visual C++ dialect of C++.  Regular MinGW GCC and clang both target the same calling convention / ABI (including type sizes) and object-file format as MSVC, so at least in theory there shouldn't be any problem linking, unless your source code actually works differently depending on the compiler.  Certainly for C; not totally sure about C++ ABI compatibility on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

In theory, if you manage to create a plain C interface for that DLL (all exported symbols from DLL are standard C functions) and don't use memory management functions across "border" (no mixed memory management) then you should be able to dynamically load that DLL from another another (MSVC) process and call its functions, at least.

Not sure about statically linking against it... probably not, because the compiler and linker must go hand in hand (MSVC compiler+MSVC linker or GCC compiler+GCC linker) . The output of GCC linker is probably not compatible with MSVC at least regarding name mangling.

Here is how I would structure it (without small details):

**Header.h** (separate header to be included in both DLL and EXE)

```
//... remember to use your preferred calling convention but be consistent about it

struc Interface{
    void (*func0)();
    void (*func1)(int);
    //...
};

typedef Interface* (*GetInterface)();
```

**DLL (gcc)**

```
#include "Header.h"

//functions implementing specific functionality (not exported)
void f0)(){/*...*/}
void f1)(int){/*...*/}
//...

Interface* getInterface(){//this must be exported from DLL (compiler specific)
    static Interface interface;

    //initialize functions pointers from interface with corresponding functions
    interface.func0 = &f0;
    interface.func1 = &f1;
    //...

    return &interface;
}
```

**EXE (MSVC)**

```
#include "Header.h"
int main(){
    auto dll = LoadLibrary("DLL.dll");
    auto getDllInterface = (GetInstance)GetProcAddress(dll, "getInterface");
    auto* dllInterface = getDllInterface();

    dllInterface->func0();
    dllInterface->func1(123);
    //...
    return 0;
}
```